# C++ adding items to a set

Tags: c++, set

I am new to c++ and am having trouble Adding items to a set, It seems that only the first item is being added. I suspect it is something to do with my comparison function.

**Main**

```
set<obj> objs;
objs.insert(obj1);
objs.insert(obj2);
objs.insert(obj3);

cout << objs.size() << endl; //Outputs 1

for (Obj const& obj: objs)
{
    obj.display();
}
```

**My comparison**

```
bool operator<(const obj& Left, const obj& Right)
{
    if (Left.getID() == Right.getID())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `std::set` requires strict weak ordering, `==` does not satisfy that requirement, yes you suspect right. But I wonder why somebody would implement `operator<` with `==`, how such idea comes to your mind? `return `Left.getID() < Right.getID();` is pretty obvious.

Comment: wow thank you. how do i mark this question as resolved?

Comment: @MichaelGrinnell: Not your fault, Slava put an answer in the comment space. I'll copy it so that you can mark the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`std::set` requires strict weak ordering. (This tells `std::set`  which element comes first). `==` does not satisfy that requirement, yes you suspect right. (`a==b` is equivalent to `b==a`, but `a comes before b` means `b comes AFTER a`)

`return Left.getID() < Right.getID();` is the pretty obvious fix.

*Adapted from Slava's comment*